# What does a goniometer (sound) show?

Tags: acoustics, data

In looking into 2D representations of audio, I came across a tool called a goniometer. I'm aware that a goniometer refers also to a device for measuring angles, but in this context it refers to one that measures sound.
From what I understand, the device shows panning between the left and right speaker. The tool doesn't seem very widely used, but I was wondering what each axis of a goniometer actually shows, including the "correlation" meter at the bottom. Also, why are the representations squiggly lines as opposed to one shape with a certain area, and why are goniometers round in shape?

Link to the site where I found them: http://www.fluxhome.com/products.html
There are also videos an youtube of them, but nothing explaining them.

Comment: Could you provide the link that you are referring to in your post?

Comment: Just added a link to where I first found them (there are others I've found since)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found on music stack exchange [Link: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/28877/what-does-a-goniometer-sound-show/28891#28891]. I't's basically maps all the stereo sounds onto something like a rotated oscilloscope, then shows if it's suited for conversion to mono if it's mostly linear, and also showing any panning between speakers.